# Plotting the functions from ParametricNDSolveValue for system of differential equations

Tags: plotting

I have a system of differential equations where I want to get a numerical plot for certain initial conditions. I want to keep A2 and M2 as constants but see how its values changes my plot. However I am getting errors and Mathematica always crushes when I try to plot.
I have tried several methods, but for a0 it gives wrong plot.

Thanks!

```
eqn = {r0[t] == 3 /a0[t]^3,
   r2[t] == (5 (M2* a0[t] - 3 *a2[t]))/(
    2 a0[t]^3 Derivative[1][a0][t]^2),
   Derivative[1][a0][t]^2 == 1 + 1/a0[t],
   Derivative[1][a2][t] == (M2 *a0[t] - a2[t])/(
    2 a0[t]^2 Derivative[1][a0][t]),
   a0[1] == 1,
   a2[1] == A2,
   r0[1] == 3,
   r2[1] == (5 (-3 A2 + M2))/4};
```

```
X = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn, {a0, r0, a2, r2}, {t, 0, 2}, {M2, A2}]
```

```
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Through[X[M2, A2][[1]][t]], {t, 0, 2}], {M2, 
  0, 1}, {A2, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

```
X = ParametricNDSolveValue[{a0'[t] == Sqrt[M01/a0[t] + 1], 
   a0[1] == 1}, a0, {t, 0, 2}, {M01}]
```

```
Manipulate[Plot[X[M01][t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All], {M01, 0, 2}]
```

UPDATE!!!
When I run proposed solution I got this plot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Usually we prefer to have code in a copy-pasteable form here rather than screenshots and photos of your screen :-)

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 I apologize, just updated, now you can copy.

Comment: I have found a mistake. When I call X[M2, A2][[1]][t]], I call for M2[t], not a0 as I wanted. Is there anyway to get a0[t] out from parametric function.

Comment: Thanks for updating the OP. I am about to start a skype in a bit so I don't have the time to look into it now. I'll try to get back to it later

Comment: Try e.g. X[1,1] and look at the error messages.

Comment: @DanielHuber You mean like that? it returns empty plot
ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Through[X[1, 1][[1]][t]], {t, 0, 2}]

Comment: X[1,1] creates 1/0 errors.

Comment: @DanielHuber But it should not, here I want to see plot for a0[t]. When I solved it separately it shows me correct answer and does not conflict with singularity. I guess something is wrong with equations, I will analyze it. Also, I will update and attach the separate solution for a0[t].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {r0[t] == 3/a0[t]^3,
   r2[t] == (5 (M2*a0[t] - 3*a2[t]))/(2 a0[t]^3 a0'[t]^2),
   a0'[t]^2 == 1 + 1/a0[t],
   a2'[t] == (M2*a0[t] - a2[t])/(2 a0[t]^2 a0'[t]),
   a0[1] == 1, a2[1] == A2, r0[1] == 3,
   r2[1] == (5 (-3 A2 + M2))/4};

X = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn, {a0, r0, a2, r2},
   {t, 0, 2}, {M2, A2}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[X[M2, A2][[1]][t], {t, 0, 2}],
 {{M2, 0.75}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{A2, 0.5}, 0, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I am running the same code, but getting different plot. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try: Quit the kernel, copy and paste the above code into a notebook, execute the code.

Comment: Did it several times, still getting something like Heaviside function

Comment: The shape of the plot changes radically with the `Manipulate` control parameters. If comparing to above, you must have the same parameter settings in the `Manipulate`

Comment: Can you look to the post? I updated and uploaded the screenshot of my plot.

Comment: I am using v13.0.1, which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 12.1.1.0. Probably I need to update. Thanks for your help!